# PHP Mailer Issues. Errors will not display

Tags: error-handling, phpmailer

I'm trying to get my php mailer to work properly while displaying errors when someone doesn't fill in the information. I had it working to a certain degree but now the errors wont show up.

*//Side Issue//* 
I have the problem where the user pushes Send and instead of staying at the same spot where the form is, the page jumps back up to the top. Does anyone know how I could allow it to remain at the form

**PHP**

```
    include("includes/config.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //echo "submit was pressed";    
        if(strlen($_POST['firstname']) > 1)
        {
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            //echo $firstname;
        }
        else
        {
            $errors['firstname'] = "<span class=\"error\">Please enter a firstname</span>";
        }

        if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 1)
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            //echo $email;

            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $email = $email;
            }
            else
            {
                $errors['email'] = "<span class=\"error\">Please enter a VALID email address</span>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errors['email'] = "<span class=\"error\">Please enter an email address</span>";
        }

        if(strlen($_POST['comments']) > 1)
        {
            $comments = $_POST['comments'];
            //echo $comments;
        }
        else
        {
            $errors['comments'] = "<span class=\"error\">Please enter a comment</span>";
        }

        if($errors < 1)
        {
            include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $to = "erin@gmail.com";
            $from = $email;
            $from_name = $firstname;
            $subject = "You've got mail from " . $firstname;
            $body = "Their comments <br/><br/>" . $comments; 

            $mail->From = $from;
            $mail->FromName = $from_name;
            $mail->addAddress($to, 'Erin');
            $mail->addReplyTo($from, $from_name);
            $mail->isHTML(true);  

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body    = $body;

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                //echo 'Message has been sent';
                $success = "<p class=\"success\">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>";

                unset($firstname);
                unset($email);
                unset($comments);
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<div id="form-div">
    <?= $success; ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

      <p class="name">
      <?= $errors['firstname']; ?><br>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" value="<?= $firstname; ?>" />
      </p>

      <p class="email">
      <?= $errors['email']; ?><br>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $email; ?>"/>
      </p>

      <p class="text">
      <?= $errors['comments']; ?><br>
        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"><?= $comments; ?></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**CSS (in case it helps)**

```
/* ============================================================
  CONTACT FORM
============================================================ */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#form-div {
    background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -260px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.feedback-input {
    color:#3c3c3c;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.feedback-input:focus{
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 3px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
    outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused{
    color:#30aed6;
    border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
}

/* ICONS */
#name{
    background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#name:focus{
    background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email{
    background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email:focus{
    background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#comment{
    background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150%;
    resize:vertical;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background-color:white;
}

#button-blue{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-top:22px;
    padding-bottom:22px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top:-4px;
  font-weight:700;
}

#button-blue:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #0493bd;
}

.submit:hover {
    color: #3498db;
}

.ease {
    width: 0px;
    height: 74px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease;
    -o-transition: .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: .3s ease;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.submit:hover .ease{
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    #form-div{
        left: 3%;
        margin-right: 3%;
        width: 88%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 3%;
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
}
```

Thanks, and I look forward to hearing from you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page will be generating quite a few errors because when it's loaded you're referencing variables that are not defined - for example `$errors['firstname']` is not defined when the page is first loaded, but you're asking it to display anyway. These errors should be showing up normally - if they are not you've probably got error reporting turned off, which in't a good idea while developing, so you should check your web server logs to see any other errors.

It "jumps back to the top" because it's reloading the page. If you submit your form via an ajax request, that won't happen.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please go into a bit more detail. I understand what you are saying but I don't know where this needs to be implemented

Comment: In your php.ini file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php Look at `display_errors` and `error_reporting`